# Does Nuxt have a way of showing users on old browsers a page with browser upgrade instructions rather than the main web app?

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm wondering if it is possible for all users that are running an unsupported browser such as IE to see a browser upgrade guide similar to [Youtube's](https://www.youtube.com/supported_browsers) rather than the actual web app.

I'm after something that feels similar to `<noscript>` even though I am aware that there is no native HTML5 element to do achieve this.

I am not looking for an answer that involves:

- editing the index.html file in /dist
- a page redirect (such as in the mounted hook) unless there is a particularly smooth and performant way of doing this

**Nuxt version**:

`"nuxt": "^2.14.6"`

**Notable config**:

`target: 'static'`

`modern: true`